In Streamlit framework how to customize the st.file_uploader i need only browse file button. Tried all the custom css method but didn’t worked
st.file_uploader()

`
Tried the custom css, but class name got changed
Had also tried the bidirectional way using custom component but it didn’t worked had used JavaScript to handle the file and rendered it in streamlit app but was receiving deltagenerator error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is there way to customise the streamlit File uploader using css
